# How to sync origin/not-master with upstream/master

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-merge

While making my first open source contribution I made the mistake of working on the master branch and submitting it with the merge request. It will probably be a while before that request gets merged but I would like to keep making contributions in the mean time.

My understanding is that I shouldn't keep working on master now that it's been used in a merge request, and that I should create a new branch to be used in the new merge request.

I ran these commands:

`git checkout -B new-branch`

`git fetch upstream`

`git merge upstream/master`

However, the code in the new-branch still shows the latest origin code rather than the latest upstream code.

**How can I set up a new branch to work on the upstream repo without affecting the merge request in progress in master?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new branch contains your latest origin code because your local `master` was checked-out when the new branch was created.

Instead, create the new branch by setting `upstream/master` as [start point](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt).

```
git checkout -b new-branch upstream/master
```